# How to prove this relation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm reading a book and there is a problem I need to clarify what the author wants me to do.

> Show that $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{ak}{bk}$ follows from the law that
>   $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$ if and only if $ad = bc$.

I've already proved the preceding law. My attempt to solve the aforementioned problem is as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{a}{b} &= ab^{-1} \\
&= ab^{-1} \cdot 1 \\
&= ab^{-1} \cdot kk^{-1}\\
&= ak \cdot b^{-1}k^{-1} \\
&= \frac{ak}{bk}.
\end{align} 
$$

My question is is my approach is correct? I'm not sure because I didn't use the if and only if statement in my solution. Any hints?

Comment: No, your proof isn't correct. Reason: can you show the step where you used the law you were supposed to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see my mistake and I do believe this is the correct solution

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{a}{b} &= \frac{c}{d} \\
&= (cd^{-1}) \cdot (bb^{-1}) \cdot (kk^{-1}) \\
&= (cb) \cdot (d^{-1}b^{-1}) \cdot (kk^{-1}) \\
&= (ad) \cdot (d^{-1}b^{-1}) \cdot (kk^{-1}) \\
&= (ab^{-1}) \cdot (dd^{-1}) \cdot (kk^{-1}) \\
&= (ab^{-1}) \cdot (kk^{-1}) \\
&= (\frac{a}{b}) \cdot (\frac{k}{k}) \\
&= \frac{ak}{bk}
\end{align} 
$$